# Ruby how display regex (in logs and screen)

Tags: ruby

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to display and log a regex value I use for to search a String.

**The problem:**

Even `to_s` doesn't work. I ended up using dummy regexD to display it.

**What I don't know how to do:**

Is there a good way to convert alpha regex into char?

**Context:**

```
 $VERBOSE = nil       

 regex  = /alpha.centavra/i            # 
 regexD= 'alpha.centavra'    # to display
 puts "1. Search for: " + regex.to_s        ## (?i-mx:alpha.centavra)
 puts "2. Search for: " + regex.to_s.gsub!('(?i-mx:','').gsub!(')','')

       File.open('D:/x/test.dat', 'w') { |f|   f.write  ('Search for ' + regex.to_s) }
```

Comment: `regex.inspect`

Comment: source: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-inspect

Comment: Tx Sudaca,  inspect takes it litteraly /alpha.centavra/i, bit better then with mx

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.source` on your regex.

```
regex  = /alpha.centavra/i
regex.source # => "alpha.centavra"
```